# Creating an array of properties from an array of objects with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
function Person(name, favouriteColour) {
   this.Name = name;
   this.FavouriteColour = favouriteColour;
}

var group = [];

group.push(new Person("Bob", "Green"));
group.push(new Person("Jane", "Red"));
group.push(new Person("Jack", "Blue"));
```

What could I do to get an array of Names from group?

```
group.??? -> ["Bob", "Jane", "Jack"]
```

In c#, the same as: `group.ConvertAll<string>(m => m.Name)`

Comment: Are you using jQuery or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll offer the obvious one with straight javascript that works in all browsers:

```
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    names.push(group[i].Name);
}
```

---

Or with jQuery (using it's `.map` utility method):

```
var names = $.map(group, function(item) {return(item.Name);});
```

---

Or, if you install a `.map` shim to make sure the `.map` Array method is available in all browsers:

```
var names = group.map(function(item) {return(item.Name);});
```

Comment: Thanks, you weren't the first one with these answers, but you provided the most robust selection. I went with the jQuery's map method. Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll just have to loop over the array and get the names that way.

```
function getKeysArray(key, objArray) {
    var result = [], l = objArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        result.push(objArray[i][key]);
    }
    return result;
}

alert(getKeysArray("Name", group));
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7sXb6/)

You could also try a seperate library like [LINQ to JavaScript](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) which looks quite useful.

Comment: What is the file size overhead for Linq to Javascript?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used it but seen it recommended on here before. Just downloaded it and it's 6.9kb.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.map`, but it's not available in older browsers.

```
// names is group's Name properties
var names = group.map(function(value) { return value.Name; });
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript 1.6 and later:

`group.map(function(p) { return p.Name; });`